# Errors using multiprocessing.pool map when reading from an immutable object

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, immutability

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing Pool class to map a pure function over some immutable objects.  However, when I try and run this, I see tons of errors in the terminal (sometimes lasting for minutes), and often, python 'has to terminate in an unusual way'.  I'm running on Windows (XP), using python 3.2.2.

```
import multiprocessing

def do_stuff(v):
    return v.x + v.y

class Vector:
    __slots__ = ['x', 'y']

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot assign values to object {0} of type {1}".format(self, type(self)))

    def __init__(self, x, y = None):
        """Initialize an immutable x, y Vector"""
        object.__setattr__(self, 'x', x)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'y', y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    todo = [Vector(1, 2), Vector(3, 4), Vector(-1, 12), Vector(16, 32), Vector(16, 32)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    results = list(pool.map(do_stuff, todo))
    print(results)
```

Expected Output:

```
[3, 7, 11, 48, 48]
```

The number of errors is very large, but it seems to boil down to something in pool.map trying to set attributes on a Vector:

```
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 116, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "c:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 378, in get
    return recv()
  File "d:\Documents and Settings\Userdir\Scripts\temp\test.py", line 11, in __s
etattr__
    raise AttributeError("Cannot assign values to object {0} of type {1}".format
(self, type(self)))
AttributeError: Cannot assign values to object <__main__.Vector object at 0x00C2
BBB0> of type <class '__main__.Vector'>
```

I can comment out the line starting with `__slots__` (strange?), use a regular `map`, or I can make the Vector class mutable (comment out the `__setattr__`), and any one of these by itself will cause it to work fine.

**Why would anything be trying to set attributes on my objects, when all I am doing is reading from the objects?**

**Why does removing `__slots__` from the object cause this to work correctly?**

EDIT:

I am using `__slots__` as a way of saving memory/space, as there are typically a large number of Vectors in my program.  Thus I cannot derive Vector from a tuple: [`__slots__` do not work for classes derived from ''variable-length'' built-in types such as long, str and tuple](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/slots.html)

Comment: Is there an alternative way to make a class immutable, which works for this scenario?

Comment: `__slots__` is there to save space with a large number of Vectors.

Comment: Ahh, I thought you were assuming the purpose of `__slots__` was to make Vector immutable.  It does solve the problem, and I could accept your answer if it was posted as one. :)  Thanks very much!

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__slots__` causes unpickling problems with `multiprocessing`, see for example [python multiprocessing pickle protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920601/python-multiprocessing-pickle-protocol)

Since you don't need it for immutability (your `__setattr__` is adequate for all practical purposes) I suggest you remove it.

If you really need it to save space, then implement [`__getstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) and [`__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) which could fix the unpickling problem.

Comment: I guess the problem I had, was that I didn't know it was pickling the objects.  According to the documentation on this: "At unpickling time, some methods like __getattr__(), __getattribute__(), or __setattr__() may be called upon the instance."  Thus, in order to get around this issue, I needed to define get/set state functions.  It wasn't quite an issue with `__slots__` not working with multiprocessing.